# What kind of statistics to use to compare logFold values?

Tags: rna-seq

I recently did an RNAseq experiment in which I had controls and experiments at 3 different time periods. My samples were distributed as following for a total of 10 samples:

T1_control1, T2_control1, T2_control2, T3_control1,

T1_exp1, T1_exp2, T2_exp1, T2_exp2, T3_exp1, T3_exp2

I did differential expression analysis with DESeq2 and from it I obtained 3 files from each time period T1, T2, and T3 that show the logFold change values from the control to the experimental for each gene. **My question is how I can statistically compare the logFold change value for one gene in one period vs another time period. I am not sure what test to use since there is only one logFold change values per each time period for each gene.**

Thank you in advance.

I am not sure what test to use since there is only one logFold change values per each time period for each gene.

Answer (score 0):

Since RNA-sequencing is costly (for many purposes), I think most groups ensure their sequencing run is accurate is by combining multiple biological replicates in each group or sequencing deep. An argument could be made that showing only one data point for each gene at each time point is appropriate given that standard protocols were followed.

Although one option is to increase the sample size of each time period by determining fold change between each control-experimental partner. It would be important however to consult the literature and colleagues whether this is appropriate for the specific type of analysis you are doing.